# How to hold nested recyclerview single item data?

Tags: android

- I am adding item with the green button
- item are adding in nested list
- but i cannot get data from nested Recyclerview row

**I have done from seeing this link**

https://android-pratap.blogspot.com/2015/12/horizontal-recyclerview-in-vertical.html

[image]

Comment: can you please show your code ?

Comment: I have tried too many solutions but neither them was working,After wasting my 2 days finally i made a solution.

Comment: glad to hear that :) you finally got solution

Comment: yes, ask your android question related to this if any

Comment: yeah sure in future..if i face something like that

Answer (score 0):

I have tried too many solutions but neither them was working, After wasting my 2 days finally i made a solution.

**This is the key code(important) it hold data in all rows on scroll**

```
 holder.recycler.setItemViewCacheSize(price.size());
```

**This is how i added nested row from first recyclerview bindview holder method**

```
holder.add_item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    boolean addOrNot = true;

                    if(productSelectedBool.get(position)){
                        Products.get(position).setProduct_count(Products.get(position).getProduct_count()+1);

                        ArrayList<PriceModel> price = new ArrayList<>();
                        try{
                            if (Products.get(position).getPrice().equals(null)){

                            }else{
                                price = Products.get(position).getPrice();
                            }
                        }catch (NullPointerException e){

                        }

                        for (int i=0; i<price.size(); i++){                 //check IF ALREADY ADDED
                            if (price.get(i).getType().equals(holder.spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString()))
                                addOrNot = false;

                        }
// if addOrNot true it should add and if addOrNot is false it means it already exist
                        if (addOrNot==true){
                            PriceModel temp = new PriceModel();
                            temp.setBuy("0");
                            temp.setMrp("0");
                            temp.setSell("0");
                            temp.setPosition(position);
                            temp.setType(holder.spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString());
                            price.add(temp);
                            Products.get(position).setPrice(price);
                            adapter = new ItemsAdapter(position, Products.get(position).getPrice());
                            holder.recycler.setAdapter(adapter);
                            holder.recycler.setItemViewCacheSize(price.size());
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }else
                            new CustomDialogClass(CD_F_Product_Price_Update.this, "Already Added").show();

                    }else{
                        new CustomDialogClass(CD_F_Product_Price_Update.this, "Please select product first").show();
                    }

                }
            });
```

**And one more important thing i stored nested recyclerview data in (model object) of main recyclerview single row data**

Comment: if anyone need any help related to this so can ask

Comment: I need to maintain selected item position and scroll position in Nested recylerciew, any idea?